# Set different color scheme for VS Code from running in WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

When developing, I often run two Visual Studio Code editors side to side - one directly from Windows and another from WSL. Every now and then I do something in one editor, and only after a while I realize it is the wrong instance... so I have to repeat the whole process in the other VS code.

Is it somehow possible to start the WSL Code in a different color scheme? So I could immediately tell - this is the code from Windows and that is the code. I know, there is a note up in the window frame. But a changed color scheme would be more apparent.

Comment: have you tried setting the `workbench.colorTheme` setting in the workspace/folder `settings.json` file

Comment: @rioV8, yes that works. Can you make this an answer, so I can accept that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try setting the `workbench.colorTheme` setting in the workspace/folder `settings.json` file

Answer (score 1):

Workspace folder worked for that particular project but I wanted to be able to have one setting for WSL across all projects. I used the same `workbench.colorTheme` with the `Open Remote Settings` option:

[image: picture of the VSCode Preferences: Open Remote Setting json file in the command drop down and a picture of the workbench.colorTheme setting in the json file]

Comment: This is the correct answer as it allows specifing settings for all wsl projects, not just one.